# Meaning of "| =" operator?

Tags: c

I have encountered code like

```
if (flagsDef) 
flagsTainted |= flagsUsed;
```

please assist in knowing the meaning of the operator used.

Comment: I think you would be well-served referring to a C programming book rather than asking SO to explain basic language features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The statement:

```
flagsTainted |= flagsUsed
```

is shorthand for:

```
flagsTainted = flagsTainted | flagsUsed
```

which uses the binary/bitwise OR operator `|`.

The code is manipulating a *flag* variable, which is keeping state information by setting bits in the variable `flagsTainted`.

For more information about bitwise manipulation, the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

`a op= b` is `a = a op b`, and `|` is the bitwise `or` operator (bitwise meaning it's applied for each binary digit).

Here is the [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction) for `or`:

```
    0 1 
    ___
 0| 0 1
 1| 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` is a bitwise OR.  This means that it compares the bits using an or operator.

For example:

```
101
001
```

If you `|` the two, you get 101. The | =  assigns the result back to the left hand side of the operation.

Comment: In my rush to get the answer out I made a mistake :). Edited, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be read in English as "or equals".

It's similar to += except instead of adding the left value to the right, it instead performs a bitwise or of the two values and then assigns the result into the left variable as you would expect.

For more information on bitwise operations, see this link:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)